# How to Page Up/Down on Anker Bluetooth Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I've got the [Anker Bluetooth keyboard](http://www.ianker.com/product/98ANSLM78-WBTA#ptop) and I'm using it with my Macbook Pro. I used to press `Fn`+`<Arrow Up>` to do a page up, but that doesn't seem to happen with this keyboard. Does anyone know how to do a page up with this keyboard?

Comment: It appears that typing `Fn`+`<Arrow Up>` gets sent as `⌘`+`<Arrow Up>`. Not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net) can remap keys to do this, but since the Fn key doesn't seem to be standard you may have to remap it to another key. BetterTouchTool is much more simple by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You might have figured it out by now, but just in case...
My keyboard has 3 keys marked to use with your Operation System. A is for IOS/Mac, S is for Android, and D is for Windows/PC. In my case, I have a Windows. I hold Fn + D(the key the match my OS) and click arrow key I'd like to use.